# VimL: How to know in which buffer Vim is, by buffer name

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm currently modifying a plugin that I like, to suit my needs. I have come across the problem that I need to know in what buffer I'm in, within VimL's limitations.

I need to be able to refer to the buffer by name, specifically I need to know when I'm within Vim's own `[Command Line]` buffer. Which BTW, you can achieve using `q:`, `q/` or `q?`.

The plugin I'm modifying is the following: https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle

And this is my fork: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-numbertoggle

What I want to do is know when I'm in this specific buffer, called `[Command Line]` and not use relative line numbers when I'm in it.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Is `echo bufname('')` sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @EarlGray It may be, I'll read it's documentation and tell you. :)

Comment: Also, you always can look up name of current file using register `%`: `:echo @%`

Comment: @EarlGray, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @EarlGray It seems it doesn't output anything when used with a Vim buffer (`[No Name]` `[Command Line]` etc.). :/

Comment: @Eduan use `bufnr()` in this case

Comment: There may be a lot of `[No Name]` buffers I think, so it's better to enumerate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for some options set by Vim when it creates the command-line window.

1. **create this file and directories:**

   ```
   ~/after/ftpugin/vim.vim
   ```

   What you put in this file is only executed by Vim when you edit a file with the corresponding `filetype`.
2. **add the following self-explanatory code to that file:**

   ```
   if &buftype == "nofile"
     setlocal number
   endif
   ```

It works, here. I think that you can easily adapt it to your needs by adding `&filetype == "vim"`.

Comment: That worked! Excellent, thanks! I used the following: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-numbertoggle/blob/683963eb3e7189eeafe1f5712d8b108342cefeb0/after/ftplugin/vim.vim

Comment: Let me update that URL: https://github.com/Greduan/vim_number-toggle/blob/683963eb3e7189eeafe1f5712d8b108342cefeb0/after/ftplugin/vim.vim

Answer (score 5):

Use vimscript function `bufname('')` with an empty string (for details, see `:help bufname()`). To get the number of the buffer, use `bufnr('')`.

Also, you can get the name of file in the current buffer using register `%`:

```
let current_file = @%
```